# Group by using left join

Tags: sql, db2

I am unable to create a group by clause in my query.
I am pulling data from a DB2 server.

```
select 

lqbin# as Location,
lqpart as Part#,
lqlot# as Batch,
lqqtyh as Qty,
lqunit as UOM

from binfxp

left join binb on lqbin# = bm4binn and lqpart = bm4part

where lqplnt = 'GC'
```

I am trying to find parts that are in multiple locations, I am getting multiple results, as there are parts with a different batch numbers and a different Qtys.

I am trying to group by Location and part number, if I have to omit batch, Qty and UOM, it's fine.
This way I can find out parts numbers that are in multiple location so I can consolidate them.

I have attached a picture of my result for one part number.

[image]

I would like to see

[image]

Comment: Please qualify your column with table names or aliases so we can tell which column belongs to which table. Or better yet, show us sample data from the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your point but a regular group by should provide the requested result - like this

```
select 

lqbin# as Location,
lqpart as Part#,
count(*)

from binfxp
left join binb on lqbin# = bm4binn and lqpart = bm4part
where lqplnt = 'GC'
GROUP BY Location, Part#
```

With the count(*) you will get the number of occurrences in addition.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to guess what you expect to see in the output since there no part you've used other than `11X3 bn70`. Check the query below, if does not work as you expect, please extend your example data, and output data accordingly.

```
select 
      lqbin# as Location,
      lqpart as Part
from binfxp
left join binb on lqbin# = bm4binn and lqpart = bm4part
where lqplnt = 'GC'
group by lqpart, lqbin#
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find parts that are in multiple locations,

This makes me think of a query like this:

```
select lqpart, min(lqbin#), max(lqbin#)
from binfxp join
     binb
     on lqbin# = bm4binn and lqpart = bm4part
where lqplnt = 'GC'
group by lqpart
having min(lqbin#) <> max(lqbin#) ;
```

The `left join` isn't necessary.  In fact, the `join` is not necessary because you have two columns and one is in both tables.  If you specified which columns were in which tables, the query could be further simplified.